# RecyclerView item decoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.

I set a custom ItemDecoration:

```
public class ListDetailsItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration { 
      private int space;

      public ListDetailsItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
      } 

      @Override 
      public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int itemPosition = parent.getChildPosition(view);

        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;

        if(itemPosition == 0 || itemPosition == 1) {
            outRect.top = space;
        }

        if(itemPosition % 2 == 0) {
            outRect.right = space / 2;
        } else {
            outRect.left = space / 2;
        }


      } 

}
```

It works great until I need to remove anyone.

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

The grid isn't resized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you notify the adapter? notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: I am having the same when i call notifyItemMoved()

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the item decoration ? Seems more like an issue with the adapter. Did you update the backing list of the recyclerview ?